# When to use int.Parse?

Tags: c#, integer

May I know why we need to use `int.Parse` in the first example but not the second one?

1st Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            int age= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Name:"+ name);
            Console.WriteLine("Age:"+ age);
        }
    }
}
```

2nd Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             int age = 20;
             Console.Write(age);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first example, `Console.ReadLine()` is a string. In the second example, `20` already is an int, so you don't need to parse it. You would need to parse it if it was `"20"` instead of `20`

Comment: Note: In general, when working with user input, you should prefer `TryParse` over `Parse` - because users frequently give input that *cannot* be sensibly parsed into a integer.

Comment: You don't need to use `int.Parse` in either if you're simply writing to the console.

Comment: Moreover if you had a line of code like this: `int age="20";` this would result in a compilation error because you can't assign a *string* to an int. So to fix it you'd need to do `int age = int.Parse("20");`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay A, thanks. That's what I actually meant. Always confuse the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you are receiving a string as console input. Because there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `string` you have to explicitly parse the string to `int` to be able to assign it to a variable of type `integer`.
In the second example you don't need to parse anything explicitly because C# is internally calling the [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) method of `int`. So internally there is an conversion happening as well but you don't have to do it explicitly. It would be the same as calling

```
Console.Write(age.ToString());
```

Like @Damien_The_Unbeliever stated in the comments. When parsing console input you want to use `int.TryParse()` to avoid any exceptions when receiving non-integer values as input. This would look something like this:

```cs
if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int age))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Wrong input format");
}
else
{
   // Do something with age (of type int)
   Console.WriteLine($"Age: {age}");
}
```

Comment: Note that when writing `"Age:"+age` in the first example, it also internally calls `.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

in the first part you have to convert the input from the command line, which is string, into an INTEGER. In the second one, you already declared an integer and therefore no need to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

While [Kektuto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704675/2422776) is correct, I'd say that the call to `int.Parse` is redundant in the first code snippet too. You use it to convert the inputted string to an `int`, and then convert it back to a string when you concatenate it. Had you actually done some calculation with the inputted age, the parsing would indeed be required.